# How to group items by month in ionic 2?

Tags: group-by, calendar, ionic2

I have a data collection that i want to group by month for a calendar list view with dividers like the attached image. How to do this in ionic 2?

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": "75",
        "title": "Oudergesprekken",
        "startDate": "18-01-2017",
    },
    {
        "id": "76",
        "title": "Talentmiddag",te ontdekken.</p>",
        "startDate": "25-01-2017",
    },
    {
        "id": "77",
        "title": "Studiedag team, alle kinderen vrij!",
        "startDate": "06-02-2017",
    },
    {
        "id": "79",
        "title": "Letterfeest groep 3",
        "startDate": "14-02-2017",
    },
    {
        "id": "78",
        "title": "Voorjaarsvakantie",
        "startDate": "24-02-2017",
    }
]
```

At the moment i have an filter pipe

```
@Pipe({
    name: "filter",
    pure: false
})
export class ArrayFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items: Array<any>, conditions: {[field: string]: any}): Array<any> {
        return items.filter(item => {
            for (let field in conditions) {
                if (item[field] !== conditions[field]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

and in the template ill do this.

```
<ion-item-group *ngFor="let maand of maanden" >
    <ion-item-divider sticky>{{maand.title}}</ion-item-divider>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of agendaItems | filter:{ maandNum:maand.id }" >
      {{ item.title }}
    </ion-item>
</ion-item-group>
```

The pipe groups the items with an months array that's works fine but shows dividers of months with no have any data and if there are items that are in 2 different years in the same month this group by not working propaly.

[image]

Comment: You can use an ngIf on the divider, and check if next month has items, if not; title shouldn't be shown.

Comment: But how check if next month has items?

Comment: How are you getting the months Maart, April, Mei and Juni ? Where in your code are you outputting these months, I can't see them anywhere.

Comment: The months end items are in a separate objects. The items are dynamic (with an api) the months are a set in the template like this,
`maanden = [
        {"id": 1, "title": "Januari"},
        {"id": 2, "title": "Februari"},
        {"id": 3, "title": "Maart"},
        {"id": 4, "title": "April"},
        {"id": 5, "title": "Mei"},
        {"id": 6, "title": "Juni"},
        {"id": 7, "title": "Juli"},
......
    ];`

Comment: You're example has 2 months provided, where are other months ?

Comment: Not have items at the moment

Comment: That's why this month dividers must hide

Comment: I will give an example in a minute

Comment: thanx, hope you can find a way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to have usefull data when programming in front-end. There are a few ways to handle the data you recieved. In my opinion it's the easiest way to manipulate the data you've got, so you are able to iterate through that month array, like following :

Your component

```
export class YourComponent {

    public months: any = [];
    public data: any = [];

    constructor() {
        this.data = [
            {
                'id': '75',
                'title': 'Oudergesprekken',
                'startDate': '18-01-2017',
            },
            {
                'id': '76',
                'title': 'Talentmiddag,te ontdekken.</p>',
                'startDate': '25-01-2017',
            },
            {
                'id': '77',
                'title': 'Studiedag team, alle kinderen vrij!',
                'startDate': '06-02-2017',
            },
            {
                'id': '79',
                'title': 'Letterfeest groep 3',
                'startDate': '14-02-2017',
            },
            {
                'id': '78',
                'title': 'Voorjaarsvakantie',
                'startDate': '24-02-2017',
            }
        ];
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.data.forEach( (event) => {
            let monthNumber = this.getMonthNumber(event);

            if (this.months[monthNumber] === null||undefined ) this.months[monthNumber].events = [];
            this.months[monthNumber].events.push(event);
        });

    }

    private getMonthNumber(event: any): number {
        return event.startDate.split('-')[1];
    }


    public getMonthName(monthNumber: any): number {
        let maanden = [ {"id": 1, "title": "Januari"}, {"id": 2, "title": "Februari"}, {"id": 3, "title": "Maart"}, {"id": 4, "title": "April"}, {"id": 5, "title": "Mei"}, {"id": 6, "title": "Juni"}, {"id": 7, "title": "Juli"}, ...... ];
        maanden.forEach((maand) => {
            if ( maand.id === monthNumber) return maand.title;
        });
    }
}
```

Your HTML

```
    <ion-item-group *ngFor="let month of months" >
        <ion-item-divider sticky *ngIf='month.events.length > 0'>{{getMonthName()}}</ion-item-divider>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let event of month.events | filter:{ maandNum:months.indexOf(month) }" >
          {{ item.title }}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-item-group>
```

I did not test this, so I'll keep an eye on this one. How this make some clear.

Comment: Tried it but get an error 'Cannot read property 'events' of undefined'

Comment: Please add a question mark next to the month variable in your template. Like; 'month?.events'

Comment: same issue 'cannot read property 'events of undefined', when i remove `this.months[monthNumber].events.push(event);` the template is loading but shows nothing but no error

Comment: Can you console.log month? Please make sure every variable is properly set. Like I said; I did not test it, I am commenting from a mobile device

Comment: Find it out en got it working, not putting it in events just in months[monthNumber]: `convertData(data) {
        data.data.forEach( (event) => {
            let monthNumber = this.getMonthNumber(event);

            if (this.months[monthNumber] == null||undefined ) {
                this.months[monthNumber] = [];
            }
            this.months[monthNumber].push(event);
    });`

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Yeah Thanx for your help strange that the nested .events version not working but without it it works like a charm

Comment: And if I could give you a tip; do your programming in English language. I could understand it because my native language. I could imagine people won't understand you