# Ionic 2: join some results into one item for ion-slide

Tags: angular, join, typescript, ionic2, slice

I have another similar problem with [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570501/how-to-group-items-by-month-in-ionic-2), but different case. I need to display three results in ion-slide, iDangero Swipper actually will solved my problem but I belive ion-slide could do something like [this](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/09-freemode.html) also. Please check the following code;

home.ts:

```
books: Array<any>;

getBookDB(event, key) {
            this._httpService.getBook().subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.books = data = data.results;
                    console.log(data);
                },
                err => {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            );
}

itemTapped(event, book){
    this.navCtrl.push(DetailPage, {
      book: book
    });
}
```

service provider:

```
apikey: string = "XXX";

  getBook() {
    var url = 'http://localhost:9000/findAll/BookApis/' + this.apikey;
    var response = this._http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
    return response;
  }
```

and my ionic slide:

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let book of books; let i = index" (click)="itemTapped($event, book)">
    <ion-thumbnail item-left>
    <img src="{{book.imgUrl}}">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <h2>{{book.title}}</h2>
    <h3>{{book.author}}</h3>
    <p>{{book.category}}</p>
    <button ion-button clear item-right>View</button>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in [this document](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/), you could bind property `slidesPerView` to your slide

> slidesPerView - number - Slides per view. Slides visible at the same time.
>   Default: 1.

```
<ion-slides [slidesPerView]="spv">
  // slide
</ion-slides>
```

in .ts file

```
spv = 3;
```

Comment: Actually it so easy, I thought I should use iterate function for the json results and return the function. Thank you! It solved my problem.

Comment: i'm glad to help. for now, the document in official Ionic 2 is missing some parts, sometime i'm dig in source code in github to figure out how this component works

Comment: Yeah but still be good in performance since they are using Angular 2. : )